# Cannot update kernel on AlmaLinux 8.9

Tags: kernel, yum, grub, virtual-machine, alma-linux

I want to update kernel on AlmaLinux 8.9 because cifs is not working and it complains about OS version.

```
mount.cifs [...]
mount error: cifs filesystem not supported by the system
```

Current kernel seems to be `4.x`

```
uname -r
4.18.0
```

After many attempts with `yum` (I am not familiar with `dnf` command) I was supposed to have installed newer kernel from `elrepo`:

```
yum install http://mirrors.nav.ro/elrepo/kernel/el8/x86_64/RPMS/kernel-lt-5.4.262-1.el8.elrepo.x86_64.rpm

# and later tried:

yum install http://mirrors.nav.ro/elrepo/kernel/el8/x86_64/RPMS/kernel-ml-6.6.4-1.el8.elrepo.x86_64.rpm
```

But after rebooting, `uname -r` still shows `4.x`

```
yum list installed | grep kernel

elrepo-release.noarch               8.3-1.el8.elrepo                             @elrepo-kernel
kernel-lt.x86_64                    5.4.262-1.el8.elrepo                         @elrepo-kernel
kernel-lt-core.x86_64               5.4.262-1.el8.elrepo                         @elrepo-kernel
kernel-lt-modules.x86_64            5.4.262-1.el8.elrepo                         @elrepo-kernel
kernel-ml.x86_64                    6.6.4-1.el8.elrepo                           @@commandline
kernel-ml-core.x86_64               6.6.4-1.el8.elrepo                           @elrepo-kernel
kernel-ml-modules.x86_64            6.6.4-1.el8.elrepo                           @elrepo-kernel
```

In the above yum install list I also had a default kernel from OS (`kernel.x86_64, kernel-core.x86_64, kernel-tools.x86_64`) that shown `4.x` next to them, I removed these and tried reinstalling `5.x` and `6.x`, still shows `4.x` after reboot.

- Maybe more kernels are installed now and **I need to edit some grub file to select which kernel to use at boot ?**
- I cannot find any grub config files on this OS. `find /etc -name *grub*` returns nothing.
- The `df -h` also shows no `/boot`. **Edit:** ok it is under `/`.
- the /etc/fstab is empty, indicates strange config ?!
- This is a virtual server from sketchy ISP, maybe kernel is somehow limited from parent OS ?

**What else can I try ?**

edit: Maybe this is relevant, what I could find in `/var/log/messages`:

```
cat /var/log/messages | grep -i '4\.18'
Dec  8 01:39:48 rev1g dracut[2705]: Executing: /usr/bin/dracut -f /boot/2ad75f1a643642c394a731eccfb1c125/4.18.0-513.9.1.el8_9.x86_64/initrd 4.18.0-513.9.1.el8_9.x86_64
Dec  8 01:39:52 rev1g dracut[2705]: *** Creating image file '/boot/2ad75f1a643642c394a731eccfb1c125/4.18.0-513.9.1.el8_9.x86_64/initrd' ***
Dec  8 01:39:56 rev1g dracut[2705]: *** Creating initramfs image file '/boot/2ad75f1a643642c394a731eccfb1c125/4.18.0-513.9.1.el8_9.x86_64/initrd' done ***
[root@rev1g log]#
[root@rev1g log]#
[root@rev1g log]# cat /var/log/messages | grep -i '5\.4'
Dec  8 05:12:39 rev1g dracut[4399]: Executing: /usr/bin/dracut -f /boot/2ad75f1a643642c394a731eccfb1c125/5.4.262-1.el8.elrepo.x86_64/initrd 5.4.262-1.el8.elrepo.x86_64
Dec  8 05:12:44 rev1g dracut[4399]: *** Creating image file '/boot/2ad75f1a643642c394a731eccfb1c125/5.4.262-1.el8.elrepo.x86_64/initrd' ***
Dec  8 05:12:48 rev1g dracut[4399]: *** Creating initramfs image file '/boot/2ad75f1a643642c394a731eccfb1c125/5.4.262-1.el8.elrepo.x86_64/initrd' done ***
[root@rev1g log]#
[root@rev1g log]#
[root@rev1g log]# cat /var/log/messages | grep -i '6\.6'
Dec  8 05:49:13 rev1g dracut[613]: Executing: /usr/bin/dracut -f /boot/2ad75f1a643642c394a731eccfb1c125/6.6.4-1.el8.elrepo.x86_64/initrd 6.6.4-1.el8.elrepo.x86_64
Dec  8 05:49:19 rev1g dracut[613]: *** Creating image file '/boot/2ad75f1a643642c394a731eccfb1c125/6.6.4-1.el8.elrepo.x86_64/initrd' ***
Dec  8 05:49:22 rev1g dracut[613]: *** Creating initramfs image file '/boot/2ad75f1a643642c394a731eccfb1c125/6.6.4-1.el8.elrepo.x86_64/initrd' done ***
```

I found more related files in `/boot`

```
ls -lha /boot/loader/entries
total 16K
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Dec  8 05:49 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Dec  8 01:39 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  303 Dec  8 05:12 2ad75f1a643642c394a731eccfb1c125-5.4.262-1.el8.elrepo.x86_64.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  297 Dec  8 05:49 2ad75f1a643642c394a731eccfb1c125-6.6.4-1.el8.elrepo.x86_64.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this is because of **different kind of virtualisaton, on some you can update kernel, on others you can't** :/

Maybe someone can post more details, I used many VPS from many providers and I didn't run into this before, but maybe other providers always deliveres VPSs with updated kernels by default.